# The site has no skin at all

Tags: 7, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The development snapshot of Drupal causes error on my server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19722/the-development-snapshot-of-drupal-causes-error-on-my-server)

Beside I suffer of terrible errors during the installation, with warnings about too many open files, I have now a new error.

> warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 1000 is not allowed to access /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/sites/default/files/imagecache owned by uid 30 in /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/imagecache/imagecache.module on line 601.
>       warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 1000 is not allowed to access /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/sites/default/files/imagecache owned by uid 30 in /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/imagecache/imagecache.module on line 601.
>       warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 1000 is not allowed to access /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/sites/default/files/imagecache owned by uid 30 in /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/imagecache/imagecache.module on line 601.
>       warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 1000 is not allowed to access /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/sites/default/files/imagecache owned by uid 30 in /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/imagecache/imagecache.module on line 601.

I can imagine I have some bad bad errors, and the server is quite very very old (six years);  perhaps the server does not fit the basic requirements.

My serveradmin has hacked the .htaccess file.

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch ".(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  # ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  # ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch .php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    # ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess,
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.'
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY oneoption:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected tohttp://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected tohttp://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory orin a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncommentand
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot athttp://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  #RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the clientaccepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*).css $1.css.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the clientaccepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*).js $1.js.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule .css.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule .js.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(.js.gz|.css.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js filesseparately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Can I fix all the errors by adding a new theme? I heard that this may help.

Comment: Have you asked your sys admin to review [Drupal requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) ? Safe mode is a no go among others...