# The development snapshot of Drupal causes error on my server

Tags: installation

After having terrible errors with Drupal commons, I decided to install the standard version Drupal developing snapshot (from January 12th).

The original .htaccess was not acceptable; in other words, with the original .htaccess file, it does not show a site at all. I could not see the installation-site at all.

I replaced the .htaccess file with [a hacked one](http://pastebin.de/22149).

After the installation I got the following results:

- the final site was blank (http://www.linux-board.com/install.php?profile=minimal&locale=en&op=start&id=1)
- after accessing to basic-site - linux-board.com i see the following error messages:

  > Warning: opendir(modules/simpletest/tests/themes/test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/field/modules/list/tests) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_subtheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_basetheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/simpletest/tests/themes/test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/field/modules/list/tests) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_subtheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_basetheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).
  >   Warning: opendir(modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/linux-board.com/includes/file.inc).

Can I patch Drupal to go round the too many files open issue,  or do I have to upgrade the server, which is six years old?

PS: The information about the server are the following one:

- Web server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a mod_throttle/3.1.2 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8a

  - PHP 5.3.8
  - PHP register global: disabled
  - PHP extensions: enabled
  - Database support: enabled
  - PHP memory limit: 64M

I guess that the file handlers of Apache could be set up to a higher limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apache 1.3, is considered [deprecated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/). The very first thing I would try, is upgrading to a 2.* version, preferably 2.2, and try installing again with the standard .htaccess file. Given the enormous amount of apache servers running Drupal, the standard file *should* work.
2. What is the output of "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr"? That's useful for tracking down the to many open files issue, which likely is a server wide issue, and not really Drupal related.
3. While all patches to the 7 branch of core *should* pass all tests, it could be that you have stumbled on a broken commit. Why do you install -dev? Install 7.10 instead.

Comment: hello dear Letharion - thx for all your input. Vaild thougths sure! Well where can i find "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr"? i try to find out and come back to report all the findings! Untill soon!